# Playing same animation action on loop without reseting position

Tags: animation, three.js

I am trying to run a walking animation on a gltf model from animationClip. The goal is to play the walking animation whenever the up arrow key is pressed and keep it running if the key is held down. For that i am playing the animation whenever first animation is completed but the animtion only plays once. It triggers the finished event but there is no animation.

```
walkAction = mixer.clipAction(walkClip);
walkAction.loop = THREE.LoopOnce;
walkAction.enabled = true;
walkAction.paused = true;
walkAction.clampWhenFinished = true;
walkAction.play();

mixer.addEventListener('finished', restoreAnim);

function restoreAnim(event){
  mixer.removeEventListener('finished', restoreAnim);
  walkAction.play();
}
```

The above code was to keep the character keep moving but it clamps up after the first time but the finished eventListener is still triggered repeatedly.

Also is there any other way to do this. I am using walking animation from mixamo and the problem persists even when using multiple animations and changing different properties.

Comment: hhmmm... maybe if you add a .stop() or .reset() in the restoreAnim function?

Comment: @EthanHermsey using reset plays the clip on loop and stop terminates it there only

Comment: Will i have to change the position of the model when the first loop ends to the new position and then play it again?

Comment: Ah, i understand now. There is no support in the three.js animation system to have the animation start at the positions where it ends, like you want. You are right, a solution could be to change the position of the model at the end of the animation. But you would have to calculate by how much. A better way would be to remove the translation of the model in software like blender for example. Only the running movement is needed. While you are playing the animation you can translate the model's position accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Where you are downloading that animation. if it's a site like "mixamo.com" there will be an option called "In place". you have to check that check box before you download your selected animation. Then your animation will play without repositioning its place.
[check this "In place" checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqdSx.png)